# Current contact email template

Tags: vba, outlook

I have code for opening an Outlook 2010 template.  When I have a contact record open from my public exchange folder I want to populate the To: field with the email address from the current contact record.

Here is the code.

```
Sub SendAgreement()
   Set Msg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("\\locationofagreementtemplate\Send Agreement.oft")
   Msg.Display
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the contact is selected in the explorer. If it is actually opened in an inspector, change the fist line to `set Contact = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrenrtItem`

```
set Contact = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
if Contact.Type = olContact Then
  Msg.Recipients.Add Contact.Email1Address
End If
```